# Excel Help for Finding List of Maximum Values

Tags: excel

I have got a sheet with 2 columns, column 1 has got names in it and Column 2 has got percentage where some of them are identical. Now, I want to list out all the names that has got maximum percentage. Could anyone suggest me a way to do this?

Thanks,
Prabhat

Comment: have you already heard about conditional cell formating? if so, please  tell us what you have tried already, if not youd better google it since explaining that is a hard way for you and for me

Comment: What is maximum percentage? You mean 100%? Or the highest value in Column 2?

Comment: I think a filter and sorting would be simplest. Sort by percentage (highest first) and grab all the ones at the top with the same percentage.

Comment: Thank you Jerry, but, cant use sorting since names are coded and should be in the same order. In addition, I also have to pass the names with higher %ge in the other sheet.

Comment: Hi Felix,
Thank you for your comments. I have already tried with Conditional Cell Formatting, but, all I could do was color the cell with Max %ge. I want the name column with the highest percentage.

Comment: K_B, yes the max is 100%, but more than one user name could have it. I want to extract those user names in a list. Its just like an example in school: Student 1 and Student 2 having highest %ge and I want those names in a Cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data like:

```
James   85.00%
John    47.00%
Robert  86.00%
Michael 34.00%
William 77.00%
David   93.00%
Richard 11.00%
Charles 16.00%
Joseph  36.00%
Thomas  93.00%
Christopher 83.00%
Daniel  89.00%
Paul    31.00%
Mark    93.00%
Donald  38.00%
George  91.00%
Kenneth 84.00%
Steven  6.00%
Edward  87.00%
Brian   24.00%
Ronald  48.00%
Anthony 35.00%
```

in **A1** thru **B22** .....clearly David Thomas and Mark share the maximum.

Pick a cell, say **E2** and enter the array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$22,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$22=MAX(B:B),ROW($B$1:$B$22)),ROW()-ROW($E$2)+1))
```

copy down until you see an error.  You should see something like:

[image: pic]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student